# Login in Yammer Embed - Pass Credentials?

Tags: yammer

I need to add the new embed Yammer Widget to a page. I managed it by simply adding the embed code to my page, but the yammer login seems to appear all the time.

I have to say that I don't have any experience with Yammer but I've read the [Yammer Embed Installation Guide](https://www.yammer.com/pdfs/Yammer_Embed_Install_Guide.pdf) as well as other documents. Still, I am not able to find whether or not it is possible to pass some kind of credentials (mail, etc.) in order to prevent the embed yammer to display the login to the user or at least have the login display only once.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Yammer support: "A user would still need to log in to both your intranet and Yammer embed instance even with Single Sign On enabled. There is an open project for our Product team to allow for just a single log in so that when a user is logged into SSO for your intranet, they would also be auto-logged into embed."

Answer (score 0):

If you add both the Host site and Yammer (https://*.yammer.com & https://*.assets-yammer.com) to the trusted zone in IE, it should pass the OAuth token after the first login and authorisation. I've tested this in IE8 and IE10 successfully.

Regards,
Chris