# Double hop Issue In SharePoint Yammer Integration

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

**Scenario**

Our organization network in Yammer  is configured with ADFS (SSO 2.0) which redirects to STS login prompt.

However, after integration in SharePoint CEWP using Yammer Embed or JS SDK we have to provide the credentials twice. Once for logging  in to SP portal and other for yammer, where both the credentials are same.

Please let me know a way to avoid multiple login prompts.

**Steps Tried**

Set use_sso property to true as mentioned in [yammer documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/connect/#singleso).

Tried adding the yammer domains in trusted sites as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317035/login-in-yammer-embed-pass-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried windows authentication? That way, ADFS will use the use_sso property to automatically login you in.